# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with @PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, nosuchmethoderror

I use Spring Security 3 with Tomcat 7. My http tag definition is like that:

```
<http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true" 
entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
...
```

However when I want to use method based security as like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public
@ResponseBody
List<Lenhos> getAllLenhosInJSON() {
    return new ArrayList<Lenhos>(lenhoMap.values());
}
```

and run my application I get a 404 not found error at web side and the error is as follows at Tomcat:

```
ERROR ContextLoader:220 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'LenhoConf' defined in file [/web-core/target/web-core/WEB-INF/classes/com/almen/donho/webcore/controller/LenhoConf.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 19 more
```

Error occured when I added `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`. What may be the cause of that error?

**PS: 1** My pom.xml file as follows:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<build>
    <finalName>web-core</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I don't use hibernate at my project however I import some modules(I use Intellij IDEA) into my application and they use. There is nothing runs related to Hibernate when I run my application. I am new to Spring.

**PS 2:** 
This is my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] xxx:web-core:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- :xxx-yyy:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- xxx:zzz:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.7.ga:compile
[INFO]       +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO]       \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
```

yyy and zzz other modules of my application that I use.

**PS 3:**
My new dependency tree:

```
[INFO] xxx:web-core:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- xxx-yyy:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO]    |     +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.6.Final:compile
[INFO]       \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
```

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you could list the EXACT versions of the following libraries: Spring Security, Spring AOP, CGLIB, ASM. And, do you use Hibernate in the same application? If yes, then also version of Hibernate.

Comment: @Neeme Praks I have edited my question.

Comment: Thank you, POM is useful, but even more useful would be to see the actual dependency tree. Could you run "mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=asm,cglib,org.springframework:spring-aop" and add the result to your question?

Comment: @Neeme Praks  I have added my dependency tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoSuchMethodError seems to suggest that you are using different version of [ObjectWeb ASM](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm) than the one that [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) uses (used by Spring AOP to dynamically generate classes).

I would suggest you to check that ASM and CGLIB JARs that you are using to run this code are compatible with the ones in Spring Security 3 distribution.

**UPDATE**: Check out [Spring 2.0 AOP: ASM Dependencies](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?26713-Spring-2.0-AOP-ASM-Dependencies) thread on Spring forums. It is about Spring 2 AOP, but the errors look suspiciously similar, so the solution might me the same.

**UPDATE 2**: Looking at your dependency tree, I would say that most of your problems start from the fact that you have two versions of Hibernate in your dependency tree:

1. xxx:zzz:jar depends on org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:**3.2.7.ga**
2. xxx-yyy:jar depends on org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:**3.6.6.Final**

I would suggest updating xxx:zzz:jar project to also use 3.6.6.Final version of Hibernate.

This should resolve the issue, as Hibernate 3.6.6 and Spring AOP 3.0.5 both depend on CGLIB 2.2.

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
 <version>3.6.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I suggest you try "hibernate-core" as artifactId, Hibernate team seems to have dropped the plain "hibernate" as artifactId since 3.6.0.Beta2

Comment: I made changes what you said but still have same problem. Do I not use @PreAuthorize annotation properly? Is there any example for it?

Comment: the issue you are having is not directly related to that annotation. Can you post your new dependency tree, now that you have made the changes? And, the error is exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for your help and voting up. My dependency tree is still the same. I didn't understand why it didn't refresh its libraries. That is another module at my application. I should solve it maven but I don't know how.

Comment: Best is to fix it in the xxx:zzz project, then that project can also update code if new Hibernate requires such changes. Another option would be to exclude the hibernate dependency when you declare your dependency on xxx:zzz (but I wouldn't recommend it), see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management for example on excluding transitive dependencies.

Comment: Now you have three versions of Hibernate in there: 3.3.0.ga, 3.2.1.ga and 3.6.6.Final. I give up - you need to sort out your dependencies and I suggest you ask for help from someone inside your organization that is more familiar with Maven.